# Open a html file from within an Android App

Tags: android, html

I am almost complete building a stocktaking app for work, but there is one thing stumping me at the moment. Firstly, I am a .net developer and so have had no previous Java experience prior to this app, so everything has been learnt on the fly.

Ok, so I have put together a "help" page for the users. Its in HTML. I have created a folder on my nexus 7 and named it saregohelp (the app name is Sarego). I have placed the html file inside and its named "help.html"

Here is my current link.

**"file://Internal storage/saregohelp/help"**

I can get the button to link to a website, but the tablets wont have web access so the html file needs to be local.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the html file in assets.

Comment: Ok, I can do that, how would the link look? Sorry if that a real newb question.

Comment: It will look like - file:///android_asset/help.html

Comment: I have tried **file:///android_asset/help.html** and also **file:///android_assets/help.html** and obviously transferred the file into assets. The link still doesn't work.

Comment: I have placed it in the assets folder in the app then compiled. yes.

Comment: Re-Compiled and run and it now works... Thank you so much for your help!